# Accessing WRDS from Python: no connection

Tags: python, dataframe, pycharm, wrds, wrds-compusat

I want to access WRDS through Python.
I am using Pycharm.

according to this link : https://wrds-www.wharton.upenn.edu/pages/support/programming-wrds/programming-python/python-from-your-computer/

I have already installed WRDS in my virtual environment.

I have write the code as:

```
import wrds
db = wrds.Connection(wrds_username='Seanusername')
db.create_pgpass_file()
```

when the code runs, it asks for my username but then nothing happens.
It does not go further to ask for my password, and no error.

Cloud anyone advice what I am doing wrong? or is there a problem using Pycharm?!

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that this works if I run the program in the Python Console.

That's weird because I contacted some people, for some of this this worked fine and for the others they also needed to run in the console.